# How to search by SQL while doing "a cut of trailing zeros" on a number field?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a db table in oracle where I have a column defined as a number.

The columns contains numbers like:

| MyColumn |
| --- |
| 12540000000 |
| 78590000000 |

I want to find the records by searching `MyColumn=12540000000` as well as `MyColumn=1254` (without trailing zeros).

What could I try? `TO_CHAR` and a cutting logic or is there something more simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rtrim(MyColumn, '0') = '1254'
```

Note that on the right I enclosed the string within quotes (so it is really seen as a string, not a number). Apparently you are treating these as strings, right? Even if `MyColumn` is a number, it will be implicitly converted to a string before applying `rtrim`.

Comment: It would see that, as @mathguy said, you are treating these values as strings, not numbers.  If that is the case, it calls your design into serious question ... that the column is incorrectly defined as NUMBER when it should be VARCHAR2

Comment: it seems I need a more smarter logic anyway because I just found that it shall trim only 6 trailing zeros, so 150000000 shall be treated as 150, but with rtrim solution it would be 15. Can I parameterize rtrim?

Comment: @DerBenniAusA - before you look for solutions, you must think really hard about the problem. Do you need to remove at most six zeros? Or do you need to **keep** at least three digits? Or what is **really** the business requirement? You can't give a good solution to a problem you haven't defined in all its details first.

Comment: @mathguy the requirement is: 12540000000 shall be found in case one searches for 12540000000 and 12540.

Comment: _"12540000000 shall be found in case one searches for 12540000000 and 12540. "_  That's not a requirement, that's a single example of how the requirement works out.  What if I search '1254'?  What if I search '1254000'?  You need to explain the logic, irrespective of any particular example.